# Can I copy an entire Magento application to a new server?

Tags: php, magento

I am quite new to Magento and I have a case where a client has a running ecommerce website built with Magento and is running on Amazon AWS EC2 server.

If I can locate the web root (/var/www/) and download everything from it (say via FTP), I should be able to boot up my virtual machine with LAMP installed, put every single files in there and it *should* run, right?

So I did just that, and Magento is giving me an error. I am guessing there are configs somewhere that needs to be changed in order to make it work, or even a lot of paths need to be changed etc. Also databases to be replicated. What are the typical things I should get right? Database is one, and the EC2 instance uses nginx while I use plain Apache, I guess that won't work straight out of the box, and I probably will have to install nginx and a lot of other stuffs.

But basically, if I setup the environment right, it should run. Is my assumption correct?

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a detailed guide how to move Magento to a new server: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server (I used it once and it worked perfectly)

Based on your text I assume you forgot to copy the database (it would be great if you can post the error message here). Only copying the files isn't enough, the database has to be copied to.

In the database you also have to [adjust the server url](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server#update_1). In the config file (`app/etc/local.xml`) you only have to [update the database settings](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server#restore_config_file).

/edit: [MySQLDumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/) is a tool to backup and restore MySQL-Databases with PHP. So you don't need phpMyAdmin (but you still need web access). Backup on the old server, restore on the new. The database settings can be found in `app/etc/local.xml`.

Comment: I only had FTP access so I couldn't do it via for example phpmyadmin (I have yet to find out if the DB is on the same server and if it is if phpmyadmin is even installed). Thanks for the tutorial I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

There is just two or three config changes is enough to move magento another server.

1. For Database settings, modify `app-->etc-->local.xml` file
2. If you changed your URL you need to edit database in `core_config_data` table. In this change value for `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to your current `base url`

**For Apache server :**
3.  Some times you need to modify .htaccess file. Its located at root directory. Change your rewrite engine settings (if need) to your current root directory like this,

```
**RewriteBase /magento/**
```

**For NGINX serevr :**

If your web server is NGINX then, your config should be like this,

```
server {
  root     /home/magento/web/;
  index    index.php;
  server_name   magento.example.com;
  location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
  }
  location ~ ^/(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }
  location /var/export/ { internal; }
  location /. { return 404; }
  location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
  location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
  location ~* .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
```

}

For more information about this follow bellow links,

**[CLICK ME](http://wiki.nginx.org/Magento)**

Comment: And maybe clear cache (=delete all files) in `var/cache/` directory :)

Comment: In folder var/report/ magento saving error report messages, you need to go one by one and solved them. Connection to database and configuring URLs is the primary, next will be PHP modules (rewrites, mcrypt, etc...)